# Why is the Provides field in the local Debian package ignored (DepCompareOp)?

Tags: debian, packaging

I'm running Debian sid and want to use [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) from CTAN. So I didn't install the Debian texlive-packages, but created a virtual local package with `equivs`. You can find the control file below:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.4

Package: texlive-local
Version: 2014-1
Maintainer: Jens Kubieziel <jens@kubieziel.de>
Provides: chktex, biblatex, biblatex-dw, cm-super, cm-super-minimal, context,
 dvidvi, dvipng, feynmf, fragmaster, jadetex, lacheck, latex-beamer,
 latex-cjk-all, latex-cjk-chinese, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp,
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp,
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp, latex-cjk-common, latex-cjk-japanese,
 latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab, latex-cjk-korean, latex-cjk-thai, latexdiff,
 latexmk, latex-sanskrit, latex-xcolor, lcdf-typetools, lmodern, luatex,
 musixtex, passivetex, pgf, preview-latex-style, prosper, ps2eps, psutils,
 purifyeps, t1utils, tex4ht, tex4ht-common, tex-gyre, texlive, texlive-base,
 texlive-bibtex-extra, texlive-binaries, texlive-common, texlive-extra-utils,
 texlive-fonts-extra, texlive-fonts-extra-doc, texlive-fonts-recommended,
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc, texlive-font-utils, texlive-formats-extra,
 texlive-games, texlive-generic-extra, texlive-generic-recommended,
 texlive-humanities, texlive-humanities-doc, texlive-lang-african,
 texlive-lang-all, texlive-lang-arabic, texlive-lang-cjk, texlive-lang-cyrillic,
 texlive-lang-czechslovak, texlive-lang-english, texlive-lang-european,
 texlive-lang-french, texlive-lang-german, texlive-lang-greek,
 texlive-lang-indic, texlive-lang-italian, texlive-lang-other,
 texlive-lang-polish, texlive-lang-portuguese, texlive-lang-spanish,
 texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-base-doc, texlive-latex-extra,
 texlive-latex-extra-doc, texlive-latex-recommended,
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc, texlive-luatex, texlive-math-extra,
 texlive-metapost, texlive-metapost-doc, texlive-music,
 texlive-omega, texlive-pictures, texlive-pictures-doc, texlive-plain-extra,
 texlive-pstricks, texlive-pstricks-doc, texlive-publishers,
 texlive-publishers-doc, texlive-science, texlive-science-doc, texlive-xetex,
 thailatex, tipa, tipa-doc, xindy, xindy-rules, xmltex
Architecture: all
Description: My local installation of TeX Live 2013.
 A full "vanilla" TeX Live 2013
 http://tug.org/texlive/debian#vanilla
```

I used `equivs-build` to create the Debian package and installed it. However when I open `apt-get`, `aptitude` or other package managers I get the following message:

> W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package texlive-latex-base

It advises to call `apt-get update` which I did, but the message stays. Why does this message appear and what can I do to correct this warning?

The package `texlive-latex-base` not installed:

```
> apt-cache policy texlive-latex-base
texlive-latex-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2013.20140215-1
```

Comment: You said "I left the Debian texlive-packages where they are". I don't understand. You have installed the TeX Live packages from CTAN, and you *also* have the Debian TeX Live packages installed? Why? The error you are seeing is generally when one is using a versioned Provides, which is a no-no according to Debian policy. But I don't see that in the Control file you have provided. BTW, it is better if you just include the full paste in your question, and not point to some external paste site. It is Ok if the paste is a little long.

Comment: why do you need to create the virtual package? do you need to satisfy any dependencies? if so, are there any *versioned* dependencies you need to satisfy?

Comment: @umläute The virtual package is so that dpkg thinks that those packages are installed, though the poster actually has a local install of TeX Live. The poster is probably using http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html as a reference. See the section "Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian"

Comment: @FaheemMitha i know what virtual packages are typically used for: to satisfy dependencies of (or state dependencies on) *other* packages. so the question is: why does the OP *need* this? the package manager need not be aware of software installed into `/usr/local` for instance...

Comment: @umläute so that he can install Debian binary packages which require TeX Live packages as dependencies.

Comment: @FaheemMitha is there a real use case for this dependency? which package depends on texlive (i couldn't find one with a quick round of `apt-rdepends`)? if you don't want to install such a package then you don't need a virtual package to satisfy dependencies...

Comment: @umläute IIRC `auctex`, `rubber` and others depend on some texlive package. I want to declare to the package management that texlive is installed. So I don't need the system packages.

Comment: @umläute what qbi said. there are quite a lot of packages that depend on TeX Live in Debian.Try `apt-cache rdepends texlive-base`. A notable examples are R, texinfo and texmacs.

Comment: The local pkg is texlive-local. The error message is about texlive-latex-base. Is that package installed? Sure it appears in the provides lines for the local pkg, but the install instruction indicate you must only have tex-common, texinfo and maybe lmodern from Debian Texlive and nothing else installed with the pkg manager. Is that your case?

Comment: texinfo is installed while both other packages are not.

Comment: qbi, then I suggest installing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the message is that, prior to Debian 8, versioned provides weren’t supported. `texlive-latex-base` has versioned dependencies on a number of packages provided by your `texlive-local` package, but because those packages are provided, they can’t (couldn’t) satisfy the versioned dependencies.

Since `dpkg` 1.17.11, provided packages can specify versions and thus satisfy versioned dependencies. You do this by declaring `Provides: chktex (= 1.6.4-4)` etc. (the version is just an example, matching Wheezy).

[Debian control file "Provides" does not satisfy dependency](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333603/86440) has more details.