# Debian control file "Provides" does not satisfy dependency

Tags: debian, packaging

#### Usecase

The package `gnome-core` depends on `gnome-shell-extensions >=3.14`. I'd like to remove `gnome-shell-extensions` but to satisfy the dependency, I have to replace it with a dummy package. I'm using `equivs` for this to create a replacement dummy package for `gnome-shell-extensions`.

My equivs control file is as follows:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: gnome-shell-extensions
Version: 1.0
Maintainer: Me Myself <me@myself.org>
Provides: gnome-shell-extensions
Architecture: all
Description: gnome-shell-extensions dummy package to satisfy gnome dependencies
```

#### Issue

The package built obviously provides `gnome-shell-extensions`, but even after installing it, `apt` still complains that `gnome-core : depends on: gnome-shell-extensions (>= 3.14)`

I understand that the `Version` field in the control file has nothing to do with it, as it only marks the version of the dummy package.

#### Workaround

I have successfully managed to fake the original package by using the original package name, i.e. `Package: gnome-shell-extensions`, but I'd rather  keep the dummy package name.

#### Question

What do I have to do to satisfy the dependency `gnome-shell-extensions >=3.14` while using another package that `Provides: gnome-shell-extensions`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should now be able to use versioned `Provides:`:

```
Provides: gnome-shell-extensions (= 3.14.2-1)
```

This is supported since `dpkg` 1.17.11, so since Debian 8 (Jessie). [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-virtual) hasn’t been updated to take this possibility into account yet, so it still claims two things which are no longer correct:

- `Provides:` can’t have a version constraint;
- relationships with version constraints ignore virtual packages.

Bug [#761219](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=761219) tracks the documentation updates.

Comment: This means that  https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html is outdated / wrong. Will file a bug or correct this myself.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. There's already a bug, [#761219](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=761219).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. OMG, it's open since 11 Sep 2014, i.e. more than 2 years...